# Is it possible to setInterval to a global var so it's accessible by separate functions?

Tags: jquery

At first I thought this was the case. But evidently, it will not `clearInterval`.

In order to make it accessible, I set up some namespaced global vars.

```
    $.faux_download = {};
    $.faux_download._counter = 0;
```

Then I seperate every detail of the hover action in separate share-able methods.

```
  init_hover_handler: function($this, evt) {
    $this = $($this);
    $.faux_download._counter = setInterval(function(){ SSK.calendar.check_load_popup($this) }, 1000);
  },
  init_hover_out_handler: function() {
    clearInterval($.faux_download._counter);
  },
```

Now this all works here **until I add objects dynamically that are to share the same functionality**

To which I use the `live` event to bind :

```
    $(".extended-cell-popup:last .job a, .extended-cell-popup:last .task a").live('hover', function(evt){
      SSK.calendar.init_hover_handler(this, evt);
    }, function(){
      SSK.calendar.init_hover_out_handler();
    });
```

Now the mouseovers work here, but the clear interval does not seem to work with these newly created dynamic items.

However, if I were to mouseover some of the ones that loaded with the page, **those** would successfully clear the interval and work appropriately.

Would anyone know why this is the case ?

**jQuery 1.4.4 ( Just because, don't hate me. )**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I'd delete this but it's actually an interesting answer.

**You can not bind `hover`. You must bind `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.**

Comment: True. `hover` is not an actual event, and `.hover(func, func)` is simply a shortcut to set both `mouseeneter` and `mouseleave` handlers at once.